# from sklearn.matrics import confusion_matrix ImportError: No module named matrics

Tags: programming

Im using Random Forest and I want to use confusion matrix to calculate false positive and false negative but I achieved the bellow  error:

from sklearn.matrics import confusion_matrix
ImportError: No module named matrics

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You certainly got me confused ;-) 
I assume that with Random Forest you mean the machine learning method, but can you tell us more about it? Is this a python program? How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: @THelper This is an easy peasy Python import question that doesn't require diving into either Random Forest or machine learning to answer it because all the information required to answer it is in the python3-sklearn package.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command (*metrics* not matrics) to import confusion_matrix is:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
```